# best techniques to debug scala code which passes around lambda bodies, anonymous class instances and things like that?

Tags: function, scala, debugging, lambda

What are the best techniques that you  have found to debug scala code which passes around lambda bodies, anonymous class instances and things like that ?

I am convinced Scala will make me more productive once I learn it better,  but I sometimes get puzzled when I try to figure out what generated a callback (or lambda body, etc.) that I am invoking at particular points in the flow of my programs execution. I tried one technique which you can see below which *does not work*... I provide this code example so you can see what I am trying to accomplish.

```
def fork[A](a: => Par[A]): Par[A] = {
  val marker  = new java.util.Date().getTime
  log("about to return future with marker: " + marker)
  val func = (es: ExecutorService) => new Future[A] {
    def apply(cb: A => Unit): Unit = {
      log("applying callback (w/ eval) in future apply method: " + this)
      eval(es)(a(es)(cb))
    }
    override def toString : String =  { "execSvc -> future w/marker: " + marker}
  }
  log("returning future creation func: " + func.toString())
  func
}



// a log method that uses a simmple timestamp to help order print statements emitted in multi-threaded programs, 
// and which deliberately slows things down  so we don't see the same time stamp repeated. cheesy, but 
// seems to serve its purpose
def log(msg: String): Unit = {
  println(new java.util.Date().getTime() + " thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName + " " + msg)
  for (i <- 1 to 100000000) {}          // slow things down !
  System.out.flush()
}
```

The method 'fork' returns  a function 'F' which accepts an executor service argument, and eventually submits a Future instance to the executor service. In the fork method I would to emit a marker that tells me 'I am making an instance of function F here!', and then before I invoke the function  (somewhere outside of 'fork')  by passing it an executor service stance,  i want to print the function object instance and see the marker so I can trace things back to where F was created (that is.. in some invocation of 'fork').  The current solution gives me the following output:

```
1438983547813 thread: pool-1-thread-1 returning future creation func: <function1>
```

I don't want to see the generic 'function1' label.. i want to see the result
of my overridden toString method which will print my marker.

Does anyone have any cool tricks to do this?  And in general if there are blog posts or articles that discuss similar debugging tricks, I would be grateful if someone could provide some links. Thanks !

(credits: if you are curious about the above code, it comes from the github site associated with the book:  [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason). It is part of the 'Nonblocking' class. Well worth studying.)

Comment: Woops.. might have asked this too soon..  answer might be here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536081/can-i-override-the-tostring-method-of-an-anonymous-function-in-scala    I will try it out, and close out the question if it does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy times are here.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536081/can-i-override-the-tostring-method-of-an-anonymous-function-in-scala) gave me the answer. The code below shows how I applied it to my situation.

```
    def fork[A](a: => Par[A]): Par[A] = {
      val marker = new java.util.Date().getTime
      log("about to return future with marker: " + marker)
      System.out.flush()
      val func = new Function1[ExecutorService, Future[A]] {
        def apply(es: ExecutorService) = {
          new Future[A] {
            def apply(cb: A => Unit): Unit = {
              log("applying callback (w/ eval) in future apply method: " + this)
              eval(es)(a(es)(cb))
            }

            override def toString: String = {
              "I am a future object constructed from marker: " + marker
            }
          }
        }
        override def toString: String = {
          "I am a method that takes an exec svc and returns a futture  i was constructed from marker: " + marker
        }
      }

      log("returning future creation func: " + func)
      func
    }
```

My output now includes markers which I find very helpful to trace back to where i instantiated the function block that I am invoking at some point:

```
        1438988219429 thread: main applying callback (w/ eval) in future apply method: I am a future object constructed from marker: 1438988219269
        1438988219460 thread: main in eval now / creating callable with marker: 1438988219460
        1438988219491 thread: main submitting callable:fpinscala.parallelism.Nonblocking$Par$$anon$6@3fb6a447
        1438988219526 thread: pool-1-thread-1 executing callable with 1438988219460
        1438988219561 thread: pool-1-thread-1 about to return future with marker: 1438988219561
        1438988219598 thread: pool-1-thread-1 returning future creation func: I am a method that takes an exec svc and returns a futture  i was constructed from marker: 1438988219561
        1438988219651 thread: pool-1-thread-1 applying callback (w/ eval) in future apply method: I am a future object constructed from marker: 1438988219561
        1438988219686 thread: pool-1-thread-1 in eval now / creating callable with marker: 1438988219686
```

Comment: Side note: of course, the resultant code is much more wordy than without having the FunctionN signature...    i will clean it up after i debug.. but the output is really handy for now.